# ValueError: The given username must be set

Tags: angularjs, django, django-models

I'm trying register a user in my project, but when I try to do it I get next error:

> ValueError: The given username must be set

In my project I'm using Django 1.11 and AngularJS 1.6

View.py

```
def registrarCliente(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        usuariosfinales=[]
        nombre=request.POST.get('nombre')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user=User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)
        user.save()

        usermodelo=Usuario(usuario=user, nombre=nombre)
        usermodelo.save()

        userfinal=authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        login(request, userfinal)

        usuariosfinales.append(userfinal)

        data=serializers.serialize('json', usuariosfinales)

        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")

    return render (request, "login/login.html")
```

login.html

```
<div class="login-wrap" id="login" ng-app="appLogin" ng-controller="conLogin">
  <div class="login-right striped-bg" ng-show="Registro">
    <div class="login-form">
      <div class="heading">
        ¡Registrate!
      </div>
      <div class="input">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="login-input-group spacer-field">
          <span class="login-input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" ng-model="user.nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="login-input-group spacer-field">
          <span class="login-input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" ng-model="user.email">
        </div>
        <div class="login-input-group spacer-field">
          <span class="login-input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="user.password">
        </div>
        <div class="login-input-group">
          <span class="login-input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
          </span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg submit" type="submit" ng-click="registrar()">Registrarme</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

appLogin.js

```
(function(angular) {

// body...
angular
    .module('appLogin', [])
    .controller('conLogin', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        //Registro de usuario
        $scope.user = {nombre:'', email:'', password:''};

        $scope.registrar = function(email, password){
            $http({method:'POST',
                url:'/registro/',
                data:{nombre: $scope.user.nombre, email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password}
            }).then(
                function(response2){
                    window.location.href='';
                },function(response2){
                    $scope.user = response2.data || 'Request failed';
                }
            );
        }

        $scope.Ingreso = true;
        $scope.Registro = false;

        $scope.cambioRegistro = function(){
            $scope.Ingreso = false;
            $scope.Registro = true;
        }

        $scope.cambioIngreso = function(){
            $scope.Ingreso = true;
            $scope.Registro = false;
        }
    }])

var my_app = angular
    .module('appLogin').config(
        function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
            $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
            $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
        }
    );

})(window.angular);
```

The debug page says me that my error is in:

> user=User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)

But I don't understand why.

Comment: As you can see in the image that you've posted, in local vars section - all the variables like email, nombre and password are None. Try printing these variables and see if your view is receiving the POST parameters properly, Or see if your javascript code is sending the variables properly.

Comment: @rayy I think that maybe you have reason. The local vars are None! But, the connection between js and py is above, and I'm looking for error and doesn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending data just like this:

```
data:{nombre: $scope.user.nombre, email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password}
```

There I wasn't using $.param jquery function because I don't had jquery, I imported jquery, I changed the code above for a code with $.param just like this:

```
data:$.param({nombre: $scope.user.nombre, email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password})
```

And finally works!

The final AngularJS code is:

appLogin.js

```
angular
    .module('appLogin', [])
    .controller('conLogin', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        //Registro de usuario
        $scope.user = {nombre:'', email:'', password:''};

        $scope.registrar = function(email, password){
            $http({method:'POST',
                url:'/cliente/registro/',
                data:$.param({nombre: $scope.user.nombre, email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password})
            }).then(
                function(response2){
                    window.location.href='';
                },function(response2){
                    $scope.user = response2.data || 'Request failed';
                }
            );
        }
    }])
```

Comment: If anyone know how make this without using jquery, please, comment this!

Answer (score 1):

Take it easy please!

```
user = User(email = email, username= email, password =password)
user.save()
```

Just make sure the name SAME AS model you use.

Don't make it hard yo use

Comment: Yes, User has the same name from User model of auth

Answer (score 0):

its because browser using previous csrf_token, just try running 127.0.0.1:8000/your_path in private window of your browser.